# What's the standard way to set up a dev environment on a Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, development-environment

I've just done a clean install of XCode 3.2.6 on Snow Leopard, to the default /Developer dir.

Is the right/normal way that all libs, and software tools such as CMake/git should be installed inside /Developer too? Is it comparable with how Linux expects standard dirs to be used for things, or more like Windows where it's all down to personal preference?

Any good guide for a experienced developer who's a noob to Mac dev is appreciated. For instance I'm confused where and how my SVN client came from and why I have SVN but not Git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you should not install anything inside of `/Developer` (not `/Development`).  You should assume that anything under it is managed by Apple via Xcode packages.  For additional command line tools and libraries, one standard Unix-y practice is to install them in `/usr/local` which is provided for such purposes.  (Do not install anything in any other `/usr` locations as they are also managed by Apple.)  But, rather than building and installing a lot of third-party software - like `git` - yourself or using binary installers from different providers which may not play well together, it is a good idea to use one of the open-source package managers for OS X.  The most widely used are [`Homebrew`](https://brew.sh/), [`MacPorts`](https://www.macports.org/), and [`Fink`](https://www.finkproject.org/).  Pick *one* and stick to it.

In Xcode 3, Apple shipped `svn` but not `git`.  That changes in Xcode 4, the default on 10.7 Lion, which does include `git`. And, as of Xcode 4.3, there no longer is a `/Developer` directory as `Xcode` itself is now an app in `/Applications` and the items formerly in `/Developer` are included within its app bundle.

Comment: I don't appear to have a `/usr/local` dir but I can create one. So any  3rd-party code should go here; is there a standard location for _my_ code, XCode projects, etc?

Comment: Regarding MacPorts et al, what then happens if I need a newer version like a beta/RC for some reason - just keep the MacPorts version and get the local version to `usr/local`, and make sure I set paths depending if a tool needs the standard/newer version?

Comment: You can put your source code and Xcode projects almost anywhere. Use somewhere within your home directory, use source control (Xcode makes it easy to use git or svn), and make sure everything is being backed up properly (via Time Machine or something else).

Comment: If you *really* need a newer version of something than what is currently provided by the package manager you choose, you should try to stick within the package manager to update things. Ask on the group's mailing list for an update or it is usually not difficult to make an update to the package metadata yourself (e.g. the MacPorts port file).  If you start installing your own versions of things, it's all too easy to end up in dependency hell and you defeat the purpose of using a package manager.  Avoid the temptation if at all possible.